# Set component's attribute inside Init

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to set an attribute inside the init method as [described here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm).

Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="canCreateRecord" type="Boolean" default="false" />

     {!v.canCreateRecord} <!-- outputs - false -->

</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit: function(cmp){    
        cmp.set("v.CanCreateRecord",  true );                        
    }
})
```

When I output {!v.CanCreateRecord} inside the view, I get the default value of 'false'.

According to [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm), the attribute should be set inside the init function before it is rendered. However, it's not happening in my case. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lightning is case sensitive so you need to set your attribute name as defined in component

```
({
    doInit: function(cmp){    
        cmp.set("v.canCreateRecord",  true );  //c is small here                      
    }
})
```